# Why is nLog writing logs hwen exe is run and nothing when run in nUnit

Tags: console-application, nlog

I am running an integration test and would like to see the logs.
Now if i execute the console app .net 4.8 I get an expected file output.

If i run the nUnit integration tests not even the files are created?

The nLog.config is always deployed to the testing folder and is present.
Is this by design? how can I fix/turn on logging during testing for a console app

```xml
<target name="filelogTest" type="File"
        fileName="${basedir}/log/Test${longdate:cached=true}.log" 
        layout="${date}: Session [${scopeproperty:item=SessionContext}] Level [${level}], message :[${message}],"
        keepFileOpen="true"
        openFileCacheTimeout="5"
        concurrentWrites="true"> </target>
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="filelogTest" />
</rules>
```

Comment: <target name="filelogTest" type="File"
fileName="${basedir}/log/Test${longdate:cached=true}.log" layout="${date}: Session [${scopeproperty:item=SessionContext}] Level [${level}], message :[${message}],"
keepFileOpen="true" openFileCacheTimeout="5" concurrentWrites="true"> </target>
<rules>
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="filelogTest" />
</rules>

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simple the relative path is different for exe and unit test and I was looking at the wrong place.